# iTunesConnect Update app strange error

Tags: xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval, xcode6.4

I am just trying to update the old version with the new one. I am using the latest version of Xcode (version 6.4) and I validate my app bundle before submitting the app.I submit it from Xcode to iTunes Connect.

After all the setup, when I clicked on the *Submit for Review* button I got error like below.

> The app's Info.plist can't contain values for the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key that would prevent this app from opening on any iOS device.

[image]

I check in my project .plist file there is appear like following screenshot.

[image]

But I don't know why this error occurred during the submission of the app.

Comment: You have compile it for armv7s and arm64 otherwise apple will not allow you to upload binary on appstore

Comment: I already setup architecture for arm64, armv7s armv7

Comment: In your plist then also added them under required device capabilities or remove that key from plist then

Comment: That build is an Update of very old app so i got this issue but now i fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As some of the comments above state, you have two options here.

**Option 1:** 
You delete the key from the plist entirely. Wouldn't recommend that as you want it to run only on devices with armv7

**Option 2:**
You can add the normal architecture of 64 to the plist. This will allow it to run on more devices, thus also getting it successfully submitted.
Lastly, you could try to use Application Loader. There's a small chance this will actually make a change, but it doesnt cot anything and is worth a try. If nothing works out, you can contact iTunes Connect at: ituesconnect@apple.com

Hope that helps, Julian

Answer (score 1):

I did fixed this issue by I removed the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` from Project Plist and then create IPA and upload it to iTunesConnect.

[image]

Then that will be submit without this error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you must check your Build Settings. I have your same .plist and I don't have any trouble to upload to App Store.

Check this values:

[image]